# Upper and Lower Summs and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I want to show the following
If $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is Riemann integrable, then
$\int_a^bf(x)dx=lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n f(a+\frac{(b-a)k}{n})$.

What I know:
f is Riemann integrable if
\begin{equation}
sup_P (\sum_{k=1}^n (x_k-x_{k-1}) inf_{[x_{k-1},x_k]} f(x))= inf_P (\sum_{k=1}^n (x_k-x_{k-1}) sup_{[x_{k-1},x_k]} f(x))
\end{equation}

where the $sup_P$ and $inf_P$ means that the sup/inf is taken over all partitions P of [a,b].

I don't know how to use the equality of Lower and Upper Sums for the prove.

Comment: You are essentially considering a sequence of partitions $P_n=\{ a + \frac{(b-a)k}{n} \}$of $[a,b]$. Can you connect this to the upper and lower Darboux integrals?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur In that case I get for the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n(x_k-x_{k-1})=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{b-a}{n}$. But I don't know what to do with the infimum and supremum. At the moment I am trying to show that $L(f)\leq \frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n f(a+\frac{(b-a)k}{n})\leq U(f)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

For the partition $P=\big\{ a+ \frac{(b-a)k}{n} \big\}_{k=1}^n$, with $x_k=a+\frac{(b-a)k}{n}$, you always have that

$$ inf_{[x_{k-1},x_k]} f(x)) \leq  f(a+\frac{(b-a)k}{n}) \leq  sup_{[x_{k-1},x_k]} f(x)) \quad \text{for all} \quad 1\leq k\leq n. $$

This should help you bound the sequence in your limit from above and below.